# regex pattern for all text infront of a brace

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like below

```
text1(asdf, text3(asdf)))
text1( asdf , text3(asdf))
text1(text3(asdf),text3(asdf))
text1( text3(asdf), text3(asdf))
```

How can I make regex pattern that can match text1 & text3 in those above cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookarounds based regex:

```
\w+(?=\()
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eL8jW1/4)

In Java you need double slashes so use:

```
\\w+(?=\\()
```

Comment: java says illegal escape character with that regex

Comment: In Java you need double slashes so use: `\\b\\w+(?=\\()`

Comment: Do you need the word break? `\w+` implies one: [demo](http://rubular.com/r/JvTFQ8GrO2)

Comment: @Bohemian: You're right, now `\w+` would work as well also. But question changed few times in first 5 minutes so my regex also kept changing with that and `\b` remained there.